# Startup Disk Creator vs dd

Tags: dd, startup-disk-creator

Does **Startup Disk Creator** create a bootable USB stick the same way **dd** does if the following command is used?

`dd if=whatever.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=4M status=progress`

Is the produced USB stick the same in both cases?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, dd is used by SDC, Disks and mkusb to clone ISO files to bootable ISO9669.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Bootable Disks

There are a number of ways to make a bootable external USB drive.

- SDC, Gnome Disks and mkusb use dd to clone the ISO file to a ISO9660 that can be booted with either GRUB or Syslinux.
- UNetbootin and Rufus extract all the files from the ISO to the USB and boot them using GRUB or Syslinux.
- YUMI, Universal and Ventoy can boot an ISO file directly.
- It is pretty easy to make a USB boot ISO files from scratch

I understand that Syslinux is not used with 22.04.

Comment: So the answer to the question is "yes, using SDC or dd on the command line leads to exactly the same result"?